# Docker's container with --net=host is not reachable from the network

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I am working on a project hosted on **Docker for Windows** using the following configuration:
Host (**PC1**) Physical IP: **145.118.70.40** on **LAN**
Host Virtual IP: **10.0.75.1** on **DockerNAT**

I got the following **issue**:
A container X (**docker run --name X -it --net=host webserver 8080**) is able to access the host using the domain name **host.docker.internal**. If X pings this domain name, it gets the reply from **192.168.65.2**. However, in the host, there is no such network! The host cannot even ping X using any of this IP range. X is accessible from the host using **DockerNAT** network and particularly by IP: **10.0.75.2**. It seems there is a bridge or NAT rule that maps **192.168.65.0** to **10.0.75.0**. Using this bridge, X can access the host (via **192.168.65.2**) and host can access X (via **10.0.75.2**). So far no issue. The issue appears when we try to access X from another physical machine (**PC2**) whose IP= **145.118.70.41** on the host's LAN. A link such as http://145.118.70.40:8080 is supposed to work on **PC2**, but it does not. If there is another container Y (**docker run -it -p 7000:8080 webserver 8080**) running on the same host (**PC1**) along with X (notice that there is no **--net=host** option used for Y), Y is accessible from **PC2** using http://145.118.70.40:7000. My question is: How to make X also accessible from **PC2** using the host's IP address (just like Y) while keeping the **--net=host** option?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a reply from Docker's support. They said that **--net=host** is not fully supported by Docker for Windows.